# XCUITest interact with elements on Home Screen

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

While writing my Ui tests I'm trying to interact with elements on iPhone's (Apple Watch's) Home Screen when app under test is running on the background. Is there such ability to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the home screen is run under the "Springboard" application, which encompasses a lot of system dialogs and popups as well.

Once on the home screen, you can pull a debug output to see what is available for interaction:

```
po XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
```

Comment: thank you for your help, Mike!
Do you know how to do the same with the Apple Watch Home Screen?  because application with bundle id "com.apple.springboard" does not exist for while running UI tests for Apple Watch

Comment: try these identifiers 
```
    case backBoard = "com.apple.BackBoard"
    case baseBoard = "com.apple.BaseBoardUI"     
    case preBoard = "com.apple.PreBoard"
    case reBoard = "com.apple.ReBoard"
```

Comment: @RomanZakharov Unfortunately, it didn't work! Thank you anyway, will keep you posted about  my research!